# How to use Polyline in cesium version 1.52.0 to connect points with Rhumb lines?

Tags: javascript, maps, geojson, cesiumjs

I am currently using Cesium version 1.52.0 and cannot upgrade at this time. But my goal is to show the polyline in `rhumb` format on the map . In version 1.54.0, `arcType: Cesium.ArcType.RHUMB` is the property to get rhumb lines. 
How can I get the same result with version 1.52.0?

```js
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer" );


viewer.entities.add({
    polyline: {
        positions: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights([-112.3268785,29.1673139,1000,139.1652182,9.6235915,1000,11.4423255,50.0235941,1000,-41.2873034,-5.1132736,1000]),
        width: 8,
        arcType: Cesium.ArcType.RHUMB,
        material: new Cesium.PolylineOutlineMaterialProperty({
            color: Cesium.Color.YELLOW,
            outlineWidth: 4,
            outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK
        })
    }
});
```

```css
html, body, #cesiumContainer {
  width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.54/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" 
      rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.54/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js">
</script>
<div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Rhumb lines were added in [PR #7492](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/pull/7492), merged 13 days ago, just prior to the release of 1.54.  The feature wasn't available in 1.52.  You could look to the PR to see what code was added to support them, but it looks huge.

Answer (score 0):

This would be possible in version 1.52 via [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/docs/) - specifically the [greatCircle function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/great-circle').

You simply would need to call this function for each segment of your polyline - passing in the start and end coordinates.

Each function call would give you the GeoJSON for a particular segment - chain this GeoJSON together (there are some more helpers that Turf provides for this kind of operation) and voila - you're now ready to upload it into Cesium via a Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.